# Html media query load stylesheet for desktop when it's for mobile

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have an issue with my stylesheets. One is for desktop, the other one for mobile. When I'm on mobile, I see that the stylesheet is loaded in network tab.

Here is the code :

Desktop :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app__desktop.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 1024px)">
```

Mobile :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app__mobile.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

For the non-matching media queries stylesheets, browsers apply a **lowest download priority.**

This happens because users could resize their windows, print the document, or even switch resolutions (if they have a multiple screens setup), and they should have the different stylesheets for that —even if the media queries doesn't match.